# in Debian server, IPTABLES PREROUTING behave differenty for different ports

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables, tcp

I have following three rules in my iptables firewall

```
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 12346 -j DNAT --to-destination 11.207.2.4:12350
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 12348 -j DNAT --to-destination 11.207.1.3:80
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 12347 -j DNAT --to-destination 11.207.1.2:80
```

1st and 3rd works as expected.
2nd (forwarding to 11.207.1.3:80) do not work.

Why it is so?

Comment: How, exactly, does it not work?

Comment: I can ACCESS webserver at 11.207.1.2:80 (line 3) but I can not ACCESS webserver at 11.207.1.3:80 (line 2) from internet. The computer where firewall is installed is exposed to internet. servers in range of 11.207.*.* are in LAN

Comment: I solved problem with following line `-A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j SNAT --to-source 11.207.1.1`. But, then how it worked for 11.207.1.2:80 (line 3) without it?

Comment: Ah, I just noticed these are public IP addresses. Is that really the case? Is traffic *from* the machines you redirect to routed through the iptables box?

Comment: yes, they are three servers behind firewall in the LAN.

Comment: Do you have any SNAT/MASQUERADE rules on the POSTROUTING chain?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77426/discussion-between-user1459342-and-daniel-b).